# How to check if a string contains letters only?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse

I have a column of type `nvarchar` that looks like this:

```
col
--------
123hello45
12345
hello
```

Expect output

```
col
--------
hello
```

Azure Synapse doesn't support regular expression. How can I find out if the rows contains letters only?

Comment: @shawnt00 Your `LIKE` expression means match any value not having digits, but it does not guarantee that a matching value would only contain letters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use SQL Server's enhanced `LIKE` operator here:

```sql
SELECT col
FROM yourTable
WHERE col NOT LIKE '%[^A-Za-z]%';
```

The logic here is any `col` value which does *not* have one or more non letter characters therefore must be only letters.

Comment: Seems like it is not case sensitive. `NOT LIKE '%[^a-z]%'` also works.

Comment: That has to do with the collation you are using not the solution, @user8314628 . This would work regardless of the collation.

Comment: Note that this returns true for an empty string `''` also https://dbfiddle.uk/SvCH6hna